# Assembly Version of [MyMvcProject].Views.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When compiling a .net core Web MVC project VS / Compiler creates an assembly called `[MyMvcProject].Views.dll` with an AssemblyFileVersion of `0.0.0.0`.

Is it possible to change the Version for this generated file (and maybe also change other Assembly properties?

**UPDATE**

I've added Manually AssemblyInfo.cs and edited my csproj with `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`

With this constellation it seems that the data is not propagated to `[MyMvcProject].Views.dll`

I would like to stick with AssemblyInfo.cs because I share the this file over several projects. (Unless there's another solution to have consistent Assembly Versions over many projects).

Still would like to give `[MyMvcProject].Views.dll` a specific version.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to stick with AssemblyInfo.cs because I share the this file over several projects. (Unless there's another solution to have consistent Assembly Versions over many projects).

You can use a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file to achieve this. This file is recognised automatically by the dotnet build system (it's part of MSBuild) and will apply to all projects within the same directory or lower. If you want to apply a `Version` property for an entire solution, for example, you can drop a `Directory.Build.props` file next to the `.sln` file, with the following contents:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.404</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

As you might expect, this `AssemblyFileVersion` property will also apply to your `[MyMvcProject].Views.dll` assembly.

Here's a detailed list of the `AssemblyInfo` properties you can specify when using this approach: [AssemblyInfo properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#assemblyinfo-properties).

**Addition by @gsharp:**
If there's also a version set in the project properties, then the project version will "win" over the Directory.Build.props version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project "Properties" and on "Package" tab you have most of the properties that are in AssemblyInfo in classic .Net Framework projects like "Assembly version" and "Assembly file version".

Also you could try to use this command to build your project: `dotnet publish /p:Version=1.2.3`

Comment: that assembly is not part of my project. it's auto generated therefore i don't have the properties to set the version.

Comment: @gsharp you should use [MyMvcProject] properties that applies to [MyMvcProject].dll and [MyMvcProject].Views.dll

Comment: but it doesn't unfortunately. I have set the properties into the [MyMvcProject] but they aren't propagated to the [MyMvcProject].Views.dll

Comment: @gsharp interesting, which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: You brought me closer to the solution. My project has an AssemblyInfo.cs and uses <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> in csproj. In a project without this constellation the Views.dll inherits the version as you said.